# Cloning Mac SSD taking forever

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I'm copying my Macbook Pro from its startup disk (Samsung SSD) to an external hard drive (WD My Passport for Mac) on my mid-2012 MBP. Using Chronosync Express. I formatted the Passport before doing this and double checked it was in Ma Extended (Journaled) mode, etc. There is about 369 GB to transfer and we are at about 202 GB copied and it is 10 hours and 42 minutes and counting.

I understand first copies of this sort are slower than subsequent ones, but is this excessive and, if so, is it due to it being an SSD -> HDD transfer, the software I'm using, and/or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Are you cloning or *synchronizing*?  There's a big difference between the two and from my understanding CE synchronizes.

Comment: Oh. It’s synchronizing. I know synchronization provides for continual updates (assuming the software is running) at periodic times that are auto set or user set, but outside of that, what is the difference?

Comment: Also it says it’s transferring at 16.81 MB/sec :(. Any thoughts?

Comment: Synch = the files are duplicated and is a two way operation. Clone = the files are identical down to the location on the drive and is a one way operation.  Transferring data at 16Mb/s would be 48 hours.  Use this calc:  http://www.calctool.org/CALC/prof/computing/transfer_time

Comment: Hmm, so has this time been spent for nothing, or is a synchronization on the first time basically the same as cloning? I know it's one way vs. two way, but when there exists nothing on the backup disk it essentially is the same as a one way, right? As opposed to if I did a synch a week from now, in which it would then go two ways?

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking at it, it appears it's been not making progress for a couple hours. Annoying.

Comment: I had a similar slow connection between a CS-equipped MBP and a Macbook Air, despite a USB/Thunderbolt/Ethernet connection between the two computers. Turned out that I'd enabled macOS sharing between the two computers, rather than correctly setting up ChronoSync on one and ChronoAgent on the other. Following CS's instructions (which I thought poor and rather opaque) and turning off macOS file sharing brought the transfer speeds up to ~850 Mb/s.